# Keeps returning 'None' even if 'True' is expected

Tags: python, file, path

I don't know why my `valex.exists(path)` keeps returning `None`, I mean it works fine when tested on its own but when another module calls it for use, it keeps returning `None` despite the fact that the path name is valid.

Here's my `valex.exists(path)`:

```
def exists(path):
  # I've imported os already
  if os.path.exists(path):
    return "Exists"
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: Are you passing a relative path? Check that your working directory is the same when running it both ways.

Comment: Are you using a relative path?

Comment: `despite the fact that the path name is valid`. Well, clearly not if it's returning None (the `return None` call is redundant, by the way). Is it a relative path? Perhaps that could explain why it doesn't work when called from other modules. What path are you calling it on when it fails?

Comment: Pick any of the comments for a solution, but on another note, this doesn't seem like a useful function to have.

Comment: @Lanaru While in the end, "return None" may be semantically redundant, I think it helps code clarity to explain explicitly what will happen if the path doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `exists()` function? Isn't it just a duplicate of the `os.path.exists()` function?

Comment: @MarkHildreth I agree, but if we're going for clarity in this situation it would be best to just have the function return `os.path.exists(path)`, or even better, to remove the function altogether.

Comment: @Lanaru: Not disagreement there.

Comment: Try adding a print statement to show the path it's checking. That might give a clue.

Comment: Without context, the path lookup will not work as you expect. You need to give it a fully qualified path - relative paths are just asking for trouble. You should also make sure path is a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

For these types of functions (I'm agree with the fact that your function is not useful and returning None is redundant but generally), I think using one-line if statement is more clear:

```
def exists(path):
    return "Exists" if os.path.exists(path) else None
```

Comment: Thanks everybody! The redundancy has been checked!! Still, code malfunctions when called from another module, it works fine on its own(I mean if you run it directly on the Python Shell. One thing I noticed is that it does not want an "input", instead it wants to be input right from the source code. I keep tracing all input(by printing) before getting to where it calls valex.exists(path), all seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (your example with the import made explicit and the redundant return None Lanaru mentioned removed) works fine on over here on my end of the interwebs. When I run `exists('C:/Python27')`. `Exists` is returned; the same thing happens when I try `exists('C:\Python27')`.

(The code mentioned above):

```
import os

def exists(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        return "Exists"
```

The comments about a relative path may be right. This code snippet is certainly okay.

Comment: Whichever path the user enters --absolute or relative -- the code just has to check if it exist or not,if it does then return something,otherwise return error message. The "return None" and "return Exist" I added was just a sample. It's actually not returning what's in there

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities could explain this.

1. The python interpreter may not have permission to the folder where the file is located, and therefore not see the file.  Or if your system uses ACLs, maybe there is a rule in the ACLs that prevents the interpreter from seeing the file.
2. Maybe your code isn't trying to open what you think it is.  Print out or log the filename before opening it to verify.
3. The filename you see in your file explorer or `ls` command or whatever may appear to match what your code is looking for, but not actually match.  For example, in Unix it is possible for backspace controls to appear in filenames and distort how they appear in `ls` output.  It is also possible for look-alike characters to appear in filenames; for example, Cyrillic 'a' versus Latin 'a' look identical.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful how you pass on 'path':

```
print exists('C:\temp\test.txt')
>>> None

print exists(r'C:\temp\test.txt')
>>> Exists

print exists('C:\\temp\\test.txt')
>>> Exists
```